# Is there a good way to convert a 2D C++ array to pairs?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, std-pair

I have a 2d array to the effect of `{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}...}` or similar. I would like to convert each row into a pair in order to insert them as vertices into a Boost adjacency list graph. What's the best way to do this (i.e. convert each row into a pair)?

Comment: A pair of what?  You can always use a struct to define a pair of integers for example.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - yes, it is a pair of integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the outer array and construct `std::pair` objects with:

`std::pair<int,int>(arr[i][0],arr[i][1]);`

For example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vec;
for (auto & inner : arr) vec.emplace_back(inner[0],inner[1]);
```